# How to containerize a NodeJS app with cron jobs using Docker?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, cron

I have a `NodeJS` app consisting of a REST API and an overnight maintenance (`cron`) job. Currently running on Debian Linux.

What is the best practice do Dockerize it?

- I can use the official "node" Docker image, however that doesn't contain a crontab.
- I can use the official "alpine" Docker image (and install NodeJS in it) however I lose the possibility of upgrading NodeJS with the easy of pulling a new version of the official image.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you found a solution adding cronjobs with this docker image?

Answer (score 3):

## Solution #1

Use a node cron package. I added some code example from a real project. Every hour I scrape a website. You can set time and place your recurring task inside `cron.schedule`. You can use it a separate project or combine with your api code.

```
import { Scraper } from './controller/scraper.js';
import cron from 'node-cron'

cron.schedule('0 0 */1 * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every hour');
  const scraper = new Scraper()
  const data = scraper.getData()
});
```

## Solution #2

Docker official website doesn't advice running process managers with containers. But you can use if you need.  I use *pm2* as a process manager. It can be used for running an app for some intervals and it can restart your app if it crashes.

Links that will help you:

- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
- https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/docker-pm2-nodejs/

My use case:

- Restart app if it crashes.
- Run app.js file for each hour.

Comment: I actually like the idea of `node-cron`, it will let me use the exact same parent image from my server and scheduler. I give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing about `node-cron` ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Use official `nodejs` docker image and build docker image with your code.

You need to run two containers, one for Rest API and other for `cron`  job.

For `cron` job you dont need `conrtab` inside the docker image but schedule the image run on the host machine like below:

This will ensure to run docker image at required interval.

```
crontab -e
* */2 * * * docker run -it app/cron-image:v1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's better to avoid scheduling a cron job on the host machine because then in case of moving the docker container on another machine someone will need to reconfigure cron on the new host. I'd also like to mention that cron should execute a javascript (maintenance) job from inside of the NodeJS container. Hope this is understandable.

Comment: Yes, then you can use k8s jobs that will provide more flexibility.

Comment: Could you describe your suggestion more in detail, maybe with some examples?

Comment: Create one docker image from node image as base. This new image is self sufficient for `rest` app and `cron` job. Now deploy `rest` app as `k8s` `deployment` that can serve the traffic. For `cron` job, setup `k8s` cron job with desired `scheduling`. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/

Comment: Thanks Aakash but I don't use Kubernetes, I just use Docker + docker-compose.

Comment: Then you will need to use crontab in the image itself. So again create 2 images one for service and other for cron.